# ASM -> Checking if method is from abstract class

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I have this code in a class I'm reading with ASM:

```
    ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager().addPacketListener((PacketListener)new PacketAdapter(instance, new PacketType[] { PacketType.Handshake.Client.SET_PROTOCOL }) {
        public void onPacketReceiving(final PacketEvent event) {
            // some code here
        }
    });
```

And my question is: Is it possible to check if a method, like "onPacketReceiving", is inherited from a superclass, which isn't defined classwide? (The code above is just an example, so the code should be flexible) I tried iterating through MethodInsnNodes and LocalVariableNodes and didn't find anything, that could help me.

Comment: What do you mean with “which isn't defined classwide”?

Comment: The source class (where this code snippet would be) doesn't extend any superclass, or not the superclass which would contain this method.

Comment: ASM processes bytecode, not source code. Your source code snippet compiles to two different class files. The class file for the outer class does not have any relationship to the `onPacketReceiving` and hence, no information about it. The inner class does extend or implement `PacketAdapter` and contains an explicit declaration for the `onPacketReceiving` method. When you want to know whether `PacketAdapter` contains a declaration of `onPacketReceiving`, you have to check the class file for `PacketAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks! That's the clue I needed!